# Call a route of post method from laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes, logout

I want to call a route of the `post` method from the Laravel API part i.e. not from the `blade` file.

this is my route

```
Route::post('/logout', [LogoutController::class, 'destroy'])->name('logout');
```

This is `destroy` function in `LogoutController` class

```php
public function destroy(Request $request) {}
```

I have tried with the below code. But these are not working.

```php
return redirect()->route('logout', ['request' => $request]);
return redirect()->route('logout', [$request]);
return redirect()->route('logout')->with('request', $request);
```

**Note**: The method should be `post` only. We can't change this to `GET`.

Thanks.

Comment: From one of the function from this class `app/Http/Middleware/SingleSignon.php`

Comment: I dont understand why you want to perform your logout request within a method of a controller. Besides why do you want to perform the Logout with POST instead of GET ?

Answer (score 2):

`POST` methods cannot just be called like that. You can only redirect to `GET` routes. If you wish to perform a logout from your middleware, just call the `Auth::logout()` function from the middleware like you would in the controller function, and flush the session afterwards (`$request->session()->invalidate();`).

If you *really* want to use a `POST` method route, you'll have to use a client such as [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)